# Php Mail Problem

Tags: php

I have a problem  with one of the websites i'm administrating. All emails sent from the website have this email address at the top: php5.2.4.winX@glodns.net
How can i get rid of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers already given about an additional `from:` header may not work at all if the sendmail application on your server is not propertly configured.

From the website php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#72715):

> To change the envelope "from" address
>   on unix, you specify an "-r" option to
>   your sendmail binary. 
>   You can do this globally in php.ini by adding the "-r"
>   option to the "sendmail_path" command
>   line. You can also do it
>   programmatically from within PHP by
>   passing "-r address@domain.com" as the
>   "additional_parameters" argument to
>   the mail() function (the 5th
>   argument). If you specify an address
>   both places, the sendmail binary will
>   be called with two "-r" options, which
>   may have undefined behavior depending
>   on your sendmail implementation. With
>   the Postfix MTA, later "-r" options
>   silently override earlier options,
>   making it possible to set a global
>   default and still get sensible
>   behavior when you try to override it
>   locally.
>
> On Windows, the the situation is a lot
>   simpler. The envelope "from" address
>   there is just the value of
>   "sendmail_from" in the php.ini file.
>   You can override it locally with
>   ini_set().

Answer (score 2):

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

This function you can pass additional headers. What you need to do is add an additional header as follows:

```
"From: <youremail@example.com>"
```

OR:

set a default in your php.ini:

```
sendmail_from = me@myserver.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`mail()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function accepts a `$additionl_headers` parameter, use it to pass the `'From: '` header:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: webmaster@example.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the from address - You just need a "From: you@example.com" in the `mail()` function's headers argument.